# Change height of view programmatically with a float value (Android)

Tags: android, view, gesture, onscrolllistener

So what I have is just a simple view that is defined in the xml and what I want to do is using the onScroll gesture, change that view's height. Only problem is LayoutParams expects integer values, whereas the change in distance provided by onScroll is a float value. How can I resize this height without losing the precision of the float?

Here is what I have in the onScroll method:

```
int newHeight = mTopView.getHeight() + (int)distanceY;
if (newHeight <= maxHeight) {
    mTopView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mTopView.getWidth(), newHeight));
}
```

Comment: I already do that. I'm trying to find a way not to lose the precision of the float and thus provide a smoother animation.

Comment: The LayoutParams dimensions are in pixels which is the smallest possible unit on the screen; you can't lose precision.

Comment: So casting it to integer should be fine?

Comment: You could round it to the nearest int: ```int newHeight = (int) (height + 0.5f);```   that would be the most precise you can get (but I doubt it will have a noticeable difference compared to a regular cast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jaap van Hengstum mentioned: "The LayoutParams dimensions are in pixels which is the smallest possible unit on the screen; you can't lose precision"

So just cast that float to an int (and maybe use int newHeight = (int) (height + 0.5f); suggested again by Jaap), and everything will be smooth and cool.